# Use selenium results after timeout

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using this Python script to load page source using selenium webdriver:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)
try:
  driver.get(link)
  page_source=driver.page_source
except TimeoutException as e:
  print(e)
```

I'm testing a webpage which fully rendered within the 120 seconds timeout beside one script which blocks the page from being in completed/done status.

Is it possible to still retrieve the page_source regardless to the script which keeps the page in halt status ?

Comment: what is the exact error you get?

Comment: In this example I get timeout exception because one script is still loading @AbhishekRai

Answer (score 0):

Try using Eager page load strategy with the driver. This will reduce time waiting for scripts on the page to get loaded.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
```